# Changing values of children elements

Tags: jquery

I have parent and child elements structure:

```
<div id="container">
 <input type="hidden" id="child-1" value="1" />
 <input type="hidden" id="child-8" value="1" />
 <input type="hidden" id="child-9" value="1" />
 <input type="hidden" id="child-3" value="1" />
</div>
```

I need to select children and change their values.

The result should be:

```
<div id="container">
 <input type="hidden" id="child-1" value="1" />
 <input type="hidden" id="child-8" value="2" />
 <input type="hidden" id="child-9" value="3" />
 <input type="hidden" id="child-3" value="4" />
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#container").children().each(function(n){
 $('input[type=hidden]').val(n); 
});
```

My query code gives no wanted result, because it always
changes input hidden value to 4. I know why it makes so, 
but I can't find any other better solution. So any help
would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#container input[type=hidden]").each(function(index){
    $(this).val(index + 1);
});
```

try this